# Unable to initialize a 2d Vector in my C++ class

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I have read every posting on this subject that I can find, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am unable to successfully initialize my 2d vector which is a member variable of my class.  The header files is:

```
class Beam2
    {
    private:
        /*The following unit vectors should never be accessed directly
        and are therefore private.*/
        std::vector<std::vector<double> > unitVectors;

    public:
    //constructor
    Beam2(
        Node * node1PtrInput, Node * node2PtrInput,
        double orientAngleInput);
```

My cpp file

```
Beam2::Beam2(
Node * node1PtrInput, Node * node2PtrInput, double orientAngleInput){
node1Ptr = node1PtrInput;
node2Ptr = node2PtrInput;
orientAngle = orientAngleInput;
unitVectors(3, std::vector<double>(3));
updateUnitVectors();
```

the error is: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector >) (int, std::vector)’
  unitVectors(3, std::vector(3));
                                       ^
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the proper way to initialize classes:

```
Beam2::Beam2(Node * node1PtrInput, Node * node2PtrInput, double orientAngleInput) :
node1Ptr(node1PtrInput),
node2Ptr(node2PtrInput),
orientAngle(orientAngleInput),
unitVectors(3, std::vector<double>(3))
{
    updateUnitVectors(); // I believe this is function in the class
}
```

You can also fix your code by just replacing `unitVectors(3, std::vector<double>(3));` with `unitVectors.resize(3, std::vector<double>(3));` too, but prefer the former.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So why was the error thrown?  I think that, although the syntax is different,  the statements are equivalent.

Comment: When you enter the body the constructor, `unitVectors` is already initialized to default. So, you cannot initialize it again like `unitVectors(3, std::vector<double>(3));` and you have to resize it.